# Jasmine: Error (not a function) when checking if my method calls service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In my component class, my method, getUsers() uses a service called getData(). In my unit test I would like to test if my method is successfully calling getData(). So I wrote a simple test doing so, but I think I am missing something. In my test, I inject the service, create a fakeasync of that service. From there, I spyon my service and the method getData. Then I preform my method, getUsers(). Finally, I expected getData to have been called. When running the test I receive the following error: `TypeError: this.httpService.getData(...).catch is not a function`. I think I am not using spyOn correctly. Here is the isolated test:

```
 it('should have getUsers() call the service GetData()', inject([HttpService], fakeAsync((httpService) => {

 let url = AppConfig.URL_UsersList //AppConfig is importerd
 spyOn(httpService, 'getData').and.returnValue(url);

    dashboardComponent.getUsers();

    expect(httpService.getData()).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })))
```

I was thinking it may have something to do with how I set up the spec class? Here is how I set it up

```
describe('Dashboard Component', () => {
  let httpService: HttpService;
  let dashboardComponent: DashboardComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>
  //let element;

  beforeEach(async() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        DashboardComponent
      ],
       providers: [
           HttpService
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    dashboardComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
```

And here is the function I am trying to test:

```
 getUsers() {
        this.httpService.getData(AppConfig.URL_UsersList)
            .catch((error: Response | any) => {
                this.showAlertWindow(this.exceptionMessage);
                console.error(error.message || error);
                return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
            })
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
                this.rowData = res;
                this.redrawAgGrid();
            });
    }
```

My goal is to have my test sucessfuly check if getData is being called when using my getUsers method. Thank you!

EDIT: So the reason why I was getting this error was because my component returns an observable, I was just returned a string. Here is the updated line. I suspect it works properly, because now I am receiving an entirely unrelated error saying property API is undefined.

```
   spyOn(httpService, 'getData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(url));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the message. It says:

> this.httpService.getData(...).catch is not a function

So, it calls `getData()`, and then calls `.catch()` on the value returned by `getData()`, and that fails because `getData()` doesn't return somthing that has a `catch()` method.

So,

1. The code you're testing is not the code you posted, since the code you posted calls `this.httpService.getData(...).subscribe()`, and the message complains about `this.httpService.getData(...).catch`
2. The actual code expects something from getData() that has a catch() method, so is probably a promise. But ou make it return `AppConfig.URL_UsersList`, and I guess that is not a promise.

Comment: Yes I believe 2 is the situation. From related errors I have read about, they all fail because the service or method is not returning the correct data. So in my case, my service getData, returns a url of type string. It catches an error message. Would it be a good idea to also post my service?

Comment: Again, from the error, the service is apparently supposed to return a promise, and the actual code you're testing tries to call catch() on the returned promise. But in your test, you make the service return a string. A string and a promise are not the same type. Code that has been written to deal with a promise can't work if it receives a string instead.

Comment: So to clarify, I need write my test so that a promise is returned. So using something along the lines of Promise.resolve() would accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, it would probably. Remember that this is pure conjecture based on the error message: it doesn't match with the code you posted, and I have no idea what your component and your service are actually doing.

Comment: Forgive me, I left out the error catch from my function because I was under the impression that the error was coming from the service not the function, so I did not think it was relative code. Once again, my mistake. I updated it. Getusers retrieves a list of users from a url. To get this url, the component uses the service getData.

Comment: Ah, so catch is one of the old observable operators (I can't remember them, since observables are now supposed to be used with pipeable operators). So your service is supposed to return an Observable, not a Promise. So you could ock one using Observable.of().

Comment: Yep, you are spot on, thank you. Now I am receiving an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined` which leads me to believe it is something with my setup. But thanks for the help, one problem solved, now onto the next. It is strange because I am able to unit test that clicking the buttons that use the same component, return the correct function. But when testing the service and running the line dashboardComponent.getUsers();, the error occurs.